# to_datetime with subsecond (e.g. ms) resolution

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a Series holding timestamps as strings as follows:

```
404     02:59:34,787
626     10:04:09,622
668     11:10:52,190
796     14:40:32,032
1022    17:20:58,314
1035    17:47:55,895
1071    18:50:12,628
1075    19:20:19,642
8902    23:50:54,408
Name: my_time, Length: 9, dtype: object
```

As far as I understand, I can technically use `pd.to_datetime` to convert it to a Series of `datetime` objects. However, looking at [`strftime`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/time.html) I don't see any format specification that supports subsecond resolution (`ms` in my case).

Am I missing anything? What is the best way to convert this `Series` of strings to a `Series` of `datetime` objects

Comment: I found [this handy site](http://strftime.net/) whilst researching this question. However, its millisecond recommendation (`%3`) doesn't work for this question.

Answer (score 5):

This is a completely vectorized soln. Starting series

```
In [32]: x
Out[32]: 
404     02:59:34,787
626     10:04:09,622
668     11:10:52,190
796     14:40:32,032
1022    17:20:58,314
1035    17:47:55,895
1071    18:50:12,628
1075    19:20:19,642
8902    23:50:54,408
Name: value, dtype: object
```

Replace ',' to '.', convert to a timedelta and add in the date

```
In [33]: pd.to_timedelta(x.str.replace(',','.')) + Timestamp('20130101')
Out[33]: 
404    2013-01-01 02:59:34.787000
626    2013-01-01 10:04:09.622000
668    2013-01-01 11:10:52.190000
796    2013-01-01 14:40:32.032000
1022   2013-01-01 17:20:58.314000
1035   2013-01-01 17:47:55.895000
1071   2013-01-01 18:50:12.628000
1075   2013-01-01 19:20:19.642000
8902   2013-01-01 23:50:54.408000
Name: value, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```